# Как корректно измерить время обработки запроса в Django?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

Как можно померить время обработки запроса при использовании ListView?

Для эксперимента я сделал вот так:

```py
from django.views.generic import ListView

class CategoryListView(ListView):

    processing_time = 0

    def get_queryset(self):
        start_time = time.time()
        qs = Products.objects.all()
        #И так далее
        self.processing_time += time.time() - start_time
        return qs

    def get_context_data(self, *, object_list=None, **kwargs):
        start_time = time.time()
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        #Какие-то действия
        self.processing_time += time.time() - start_time
        context.update({'speed': self.processing_time})
        return context
```

Будет ли speed отражать реальное время обработки запроса?

Comment: Через middleware наверно правильнее всего. А ещё правильнее наверно через nginx, но это если он есть

Comment: @andreymal, не, nginx нет. Я пока на встроенном сервере джанги. А через middleware как?

Comment: Измерять get_queryset таким способом нет никакого смысла, потому что строчка Products.objects.all() не делает абсолютно ничего и отработает за микросекунды

Comment: @andreymal Ну там на самом деле не только objects.all(), там дальше по различным условиям этот queryset фильтруется

Comment: Это тоже ничего не делающие микросекунды. Составить queryset - очень быстрая операция, в то время как запрос к базе может занять многие секунды, а запрос к базе вы таким образом не измеряете

Comment: @andreymal а как его измерить из джанго?

Comment: Написать middleware, перед началом обработки запроса засечь время, после обработки посчитать прошедшие секунды. Про middleware есть в документации

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47937566/how-to-calculate-response-time-in-django-python

Comment: @andreymal спасибо

Answer (score 1):

Если не использовать [django debug toolbar](https://django-debug-toolbar.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) или custom middleware наиболее подходящим решением для измерения время обработки запроса именно в контексте `ListView`, на мой взгляд, является переопределенный `dispatch` внутри тела `ListView`:

```
def dispatch(self, *args, **kwargs):
    start_time = time.time()
    response = super().dispatch(*args, **kwargs)
    total = (time.time() - start_time) * 1000
    # print(total)
    # or
    # response['X-total-time'] = total
    return response
```